# how to create a seq<seq<int*int>> value

Tags: f#

Assume there is a `NxN board`, I want to create a `seq<seq<int*int>>` containing all of the lines on the board. I cannot use mutable variable.
For example, input `N` is 2, the output will be:

```
seq [seq[(0,0);(0,1)];seq[(1,0);(1,1)];seq[(0,0);
(1,0)];seq[(0,1);(1,1)];seq[(0,0);(1,1)];seq[(0,1);(1,0)]]
```

There are six lines including Horizontal, Vertical and Diagonal lines on the board.

```
let f (n:int) : seq<seq<int*int>> =    
    let seq1 = seq{ for x in 0 .. n-1 do yield 0,x}
    ...
```

I can create a single line. I cannot combine all lines into a seq[] by a loop.

```
let loop = 
    for j in 0 .. n-1 do
        let seq1 (j:int) = seq{ for x in 0 .. n-1 do yield j,x}
```

I have an idea that is use for loop to create the lines. But I have no idea how to store the seq1 value and combine with a new seq1 value.

Comment: Hi @samsam_rabbit. Welcome. You are much more likely to get an answer if you try implement something and share what you have tried and what problem you run into. Please solve this problem for me is seldom well received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this, but I like the `seq` builder:

```ml
let positions = 
  seq {
    for x in 0..10 do
      for y in 0..10 do
        yield (x, y)
  }
```